# how make update query in Aws DynamoDB using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to update one item of DynamoDB, here is my Code.

```
const Aws = require('aws-sdk');
const endPoint= 'http://dynamodb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com';
const IAm_user_Key=process.env.IAM_USER_KEY;
const IAm_user_Secret=process.env.IAM_USER_SECRET;

Aws.config.update({ accessKeyId:IAm_user_Key,secretAccessKey:IAm_user_Secret,region:'us-east-2',endpoint:endPoint });

var docClient = new Aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var table = "cards";

var params={
        TableName:table,
        key:{ "cardid":clientData.data.cardid},
        AttributeValue:{"data":clientData.data}
  }

docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            } else {
                console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            }
        })
```

I am facing issues while running this code here my error.

Unable to update item. Error JSON: {
"message": "Missing required key 'Key' in params",
"code": "MissingRequiredParameter",
"time": "2019-07-20T07:47:06.490Z"
}

But you can see I have Key object in params but still struggling for this.

Comment: If you want to put, you should use docClient.update instead of docClient.put. Refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-document-client.html for more information. It looks like you're passing update params to the put method.

Comment: @Armin Sorry my mistake, I edit my question I need to docClient.update instead of put

Answer (score 4):

I read docs too many times but there is a silly mistake, I found it is just typo error "key" in params should be "Key" K in uppercase only and this is working.

Comment: I made a same mistake :D

Comment: I have the same issue, but my Key is in caps :(

Answer (score 0):

## The problem is in Key,
You need to use primary key to find which row will you update in Table Like SQL such as Primary Key. IN DynamoDB
Primary Key = PK+SK
example if your:
PK = 'cardid' AND SK = 'name'

```
var params={
        TableName:table,
        Key:{ "cardid":clientData.data.cardid, 'name': req.body.name},
        AttributeValue:{"data":clientData.data}
  }
```